# How do I acquire the Combat Acumen ability?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I'm wanting to complete this Steam achievement on The Witcher 2.

[image]

**How do I acquire the Combat Acumen ability?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Combat Acumen](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Combat_acumen#Swordsmanship_tree) is the second from last unlock/ability in the Swordsmanship tree.

[image: Combat Acumen]

You'll need to level up, presumably focusing on the Swordsmanship tree, until you can unlock the skill. By the look of the image above, you'll need to be at least level 16.